# не добавляется запись в mysql через php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, openserver

```
<?php 
$connection = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','mysql','mysql','test');

if ( $connection == false ) {
    echo 'rukozhop';
    mysqli_connect_error();
    die();
} else {
    echo 'have funn';    
}



if (isset($_POST["Name"])) {

$sql = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO 'test_table' ( 'name', 'email','question') values('{$_POST['name']}','{$_POST['mail']}','{$_POST['question']}')");
if ($sql) {
    echo '<p>Данные успешно добавлены в таблицу.</p>';
  } else {
    echo '<p>Произошла ошибка: ' . mysqli_error($link) . '</p>';
  }
}
?>

   <?php
   $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM  test_table");


     ?>

         <ul>

          <?php 
              while(($cat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)))
                 {
                   echo '<li>' .   $cat['id'] .'.' . $cat['name'] .'.'. $cat['question'] . '</li>';
                 }
             ?>

           </ul>


     <?php 
     echo 'end<br><br>';
     mysqli_close($connection);
     ?>
```

Comment: Первая ошибка в используемой ковычке, вместо нее в запросах должен быть апостроф `\`` Вторая ошибка в том что вот так как у вас параметры не передаются. `'{$_POST['name']}',`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так

```
$sql = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO `test_table` (`name`, `email`,`question`) values('".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['mail']."','".$_POST['question']."');");
```

Теперь пояснения:

1. В наименованиях столбцов и таблиц вместо одинарной `'` кавычки используется апостроф `
2. Вы формируете строку запроса в ручную, не параметрами, и значит в строку надо подставлять значения переменных а не их имена `"...'".$_POST['mail']."'..."`

Comment: еще исправил Name на name и зарабоотало

Comment: Да. Этого я сразу не заметил) переменные и текстовые ключи массивов в php регистрозависимы